# Database migration problem

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, development, sql-server, administration

We have recently migrated our MOSS databases from **MS SQL Express 2005** to **MS SQL 2008** both intances running on the same **Windows 2003 server**.

After "successful" migration we switched the 2005 server off and test that everything still working as expected which it did! (or at least we thought it did).

All its apparently working fine exept that after few minutes we started receiving an error on the aevent viewer saying that **couldn't find SERVER\SQL2005\MOSS_ConfigDatabase** so we swtiched back on and start to research about what could the problem be?

After few hours of research we found out that it seems that all the timer-jobs are executed from the old database on **MS SQL 2005**. So we went in to the config database and we realize that the table **TimerRunningJobs** on the 2008 config database was empty where the same table on config database on 2005 contains all the active timer-jobs with recent dates.

Did any one seen this before? and if so how should it be fixed?.
maybe is there a way that I could write some code to recreate the timer-jobs on the new database?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What SP/CU level was your MOSS installation at when you migrated?  How did you perform the migration?

Comment: thanks for your response, the migration was only at database level from 2005 to 2008 on the same MOSS Install. Version was and still is MOSS 2007 SP1/12.0.0.6514 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem with our database was that for some reason psconfig didn't renamed the object for the old server instance in stead it created a new one and keeping the old too.
We tried manually rename the object on the database but that didn't work because the key field is the SQL instance.

SO after doing some research we solved our problem by creating an alias on the new SQL server with the name of the old SQL server.

please see here http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2008/06/moving-databases-easy-way.html fro more info about this.

I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

How did you move the configuration database?

You need to use **psconfig.exe -cmd configdb -disconnect**  and **psconfig.exe -cmd configdb -connect** to move (and optionally rename) the config db.

Comment: Yes we used dpsconfig.exe to disconnect and connect the database (we also changed the name) and all the rest is working using the new database ? it seems to be only the timer-jobs that didn't. if I try it again the will lose the configuration changed after migration :(.
Thanks for your reply.